# Solve a system of equations with a constraint to x in Matlab

Tags: matlab, constraints, equation-solving, triangular

I have given a `nxn` upper triangular matrix `R` and I want to solve the system of equations `Rx=0` where `x` is a vector of size `n`. Moreover the lowermost diagonalement of `R` is `0` (`R(n,n)=0`). Therefore I want to set `x(n)=1`.

I tried some loops but I do not know how to solve it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's guaranteed that R has a zero eigenvalue, and the solution you want is a multiple of the eigenvector corresponding to that eigenvalue. Let's create some matrix R first:

```
>> R = triu(rand(3, 3));
>> R(3, 3) = 0;
>> R

R = 

    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785
         0    0.6324    0.5469
         0         0         0
```

Now let's get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

```
>> [V, E] = eig(R)

V =

    1.0000   -0.9806    0.4289
         0    0.1958   -0.5909
         0         0    0.6833


E =

    0.8147         0         0
         0    0.6324         0
         0         0         0
```

The eigenvectors are the diagonal elements of E

```
>> E = diag(E);
>> index = find(abs(E) < 1e-16); %// NB don't use find(E==0) because of fp problems...
```

Now pull out the correct eigenvector

```
>> v = V(:, index);
```

and make sure its final element is equal to 1

```
>> v = v / v(end)

v =

    0.6277
   -0.8648
    1.0000
```

You can check that this is the solution you want

```
>> R * v

ans =

     0
     0
     0
```

Comment: I tried your example with triu(rand(6,6)) and defined the last 3 diagonal elements to 0 (R(4,4)=0, R(5,5)=0. R(6,6)=0) and your solution isn`t working there.

Comment: That's because you asked me for a solution where the last diagonal entry R(6,6) was zero. There's no reason it should also work when there is more than one zero diagonal entry.